# Azure Data Factory: Failed to turn on Interactive Authoring Capability

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a ADF setup in a VDI, an azure auto resolving integration runtime is setup for the Managed virtual network. Virtual Network Configuration is Enabled. But the interactive authoring isn't enabling, whenever I turn it on, it tries for a few minutes and a error message stating "Failed to enable Interactive Authoring Capability".

Kindly provide a solution and steps to resolve the issue, I'm not pasting any screenshots other than the error due to security reasons.
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Data Factory: Failed to turn on Interactive Authoring Capability

This issue can cause because of multiple reasons such as permission issue, Verify ADF configuration about virtual network.

To resolve this:

- Make sure the user you are using to enable Interactive Authoring has contributor role on resource group.

[image]

- Verify that the managed virtual network, the Azure Data Factory service, and your VDI environment are all connected properly. Verify that the essential communication is not being blocked by any firewall rules or network security groups.

Comment: HI Naveen, thank you for your answer. I'm a fairly new to Networking, could you kindly provide the steps for me to check whether Managed Virtual Network, ADF and VDI are connected properly.

Comment: The environment was created through code. The environment was deleted as a whole and recreated manually through portal. Now it works fine. Not sure what went wrong.